# In Python, what to return for no results, False or None?

Tags: python, pep8

I have a function which searches for results to a query. If there's no results what is recommended to return, False or None?

I suppose it's not that important but I'd like to follow best practice.

Comment: If the function returns a non-empty list if there *are* results, it may make more sense to return the empty list `[]` if there are none, then a piece of code like `for item in get_result_list(): ...` will work either way.

Comment: `False` is meaningful when there can be `True`. `None` or an empty container seems to make more sense.

Comment: A positive result would be a short string in this case.

Comment: @user2387035 In that case, I'd either return `None` or raise an exception, depending on the use-case.

Comment: For comparison, if you have a dictionary `d={'a': '2'}`, then `d.get('b')` will return None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely not return `False`. But there are other options than just `None` vs. `False`.

---

> A positive result would be a short string in this case.

So, a negative result can be an *empty* string. (Unless that's also a possible positive result, of course.)

As [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) says:

> For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty sequences are false.

But that's not a complete answer to your question (nor is it an iron-clad rule in the first place). You have to think through the pros and cons and decide which are most important in your actual use.

---

I think the biggest issue is this: If you return `''`, code that tries to use the result as a string will work. If you return `None`, that same code will raise an exception.

For example, here's a simplified version of some code I've got lying around:

```
result = query_function(foo, bar)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(result)
for div in soup.find_all('div'):
    print(div['id'])
```

My `query_function` returns `''`, so the code will successfully print out no IDs. That's what I want for my script. But for a different use case, it might be better to raise an exception. In that case, I'd make `query_function` return `None`.

---

Or, of course, you can just make `query_function` itself raise an exception, as in Aya's answer.

---

You may want to look over the standard string methods, `re` methods, and other search functions in the stdlib (maybe even look at `sqlite`, etc.) to see what they do. (Note that in a few cases, there are matching pairs of value-returning and exception-raising functions, like `str.find` and `str.index`, so the answer might not be either one or the other, but both.)

Comment: +1 Good answer. I'd considered adding the suggestion of returning the empty string, but it wasn't clear from the question as to whether that was a valid positive result.

Comment: @Aya: It's not clear to me either, but I figured the OP would know, and thinking about that question is probably important to the overall question.

Answer (score 3):

> A positive result would be a short string in this case.

Assuming you have something like this (extremely trivial) example...

```
the_things = {'foo', 'bar'}

def find_the_thing(the_thing):
    if the_thing in the_things:
        return the_thing
```

...it will return `None` by default if the thing is not found, which is okay, and you can use it like this...

```
the_thing = find_the_thing('blah')
if the_thing is not None:
    do_something_with(the_thing)
else:
    do_something_else()
```

...but it's sometimes better to raise an exception like this....

```
the_things = {'foo', 'bar'}

def find_the_thing(the_thing):
    if the_thing in the_things:
        return the_thing
    raise KeyError(the_thing)
```

...which you can use like this...

```
try:
    do_something_with(find_the_thing('blah'))
except KeyError:
    do_something_else()
```

...which might be more readable.

Comment: `raise KeyError, the_thing` is somewhat deprecated - instead use `raise KeyError(the_thing)`

Comment: you could also `return default` if none found where `default` is `None` by default. Both `return default` and `raise KeyError` could be useful

Answer (score 1):

I would return an empty list, it will save you headaches when looking at the return values of this function down the road.

If you want your program to die when you make assumptions that the list has elements however, None is a good choice.

Comment: Probably worth reading the question comments - a positive result returns a string, not a list, so a negative result returning a list doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: In that case an empty string, sorry for reading comprehension fail. String and list are similar though.

Answer (score 0):

How about not returning anything but yielding the results one by one? Generators are generally a convenient thing, as they avoid building up lists that are then used and discarded one by one anyway.