# What exception should be raised when there are no results

Tags: python, exception, pep8

I’m using a function that performs a query, and returns either some or no results. When no results are returned, I want to raise an exception to either stop the script execution, or possibly catch it from some outer context.

What exception should be raised in that case? Are there any pep recommendations about this?

Note that I’m not asking what the query function should return when there are no results ([this has already been covered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16594103)).

Comment: Most likely a simple `ValueError` with some appropriate message.

Comment: Not `ValueError`, it is for "when an operation or function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value" . Refer [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError)

Answer (score 2):

As this is a pretty specific case that doesn't match any of Python's built in exceptions, I'd probably declare a new one and raise that:

```
class NoResultsFoundError(Exception):
    pass
```

Python does also have a generic exception to be used when no other exception seems to apply, called `RuntimeError`:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html

But using that would be less informative than using your own.